# Kendo DropDownList is not opening inside KendoTreeView

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-dropdown

I am new to kendo TreeView so please bear with me.

I am trying to bind a kendo dropdownlist in each row of Kendo TreeView.
I am able to bind kendoDropdownList successfully but when I am trying to open the dropdown it closes very quickly and the user is not able to select the value.

Please check my code in below link

https://dojo.telerik.com/@Abhishek/EwamowIv

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the reply.

I have changed my approach to bind the dropdown in Kendo Treeview.

Instead of binding Kendo DropDownList I have created dropdown through javascript and bind it with the datasource.

Please check below my approach, hope it may help someone.

https://dojo.telerik.com/@Abhishek/udAcuYel

Answer (score 1):

From the [Telerik forums](https://www.telerik.com/forums/dropdownlist-inside-treeview---error-when-select-treeview-item-event-), my bold

> The current scenario is not supported. There is a conflict between the
>   DropDownList and the TreeView items. Additionally **each time the
>   DropDownList is clicked, the TreeView item is selected, which is
>   triggering a refresh of the template**. Please reconsider the current
>   implementation and try a different approach.